# Failed to build FileMQ, "cannot link with -lczmq", czmq is installed already

Tags: build, zeromq, failed-installation, filemq

I am getting this error:

> `configure: error: cannot link with -lczmq, install libczmq.`

on doing `./configure && make check`.

I have installed libzmq, czmq and libsodium right before compilation, so it's the latest from repo.
How can I fix it?

Comment: how did you install? Did you tell configure to look into the directory where you've installed libczmq to? (also, you probably shouldn't install stuff from hand that your package manager has)

Comment: Used guide on https://github.com/zeromq/filemq.

So...
./autogen.sh
./configure && make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig

Comment: Then it was very likely installed to `/usr/local/` instead of `/usr/`, where configure looks by default. Really, however, don't try to build libraries by hand that your package manager ships. I'd recommend a `sudo make uninstall`, followed by  perusing your package manager (`apt-get`, `dnf`, `pacman`, `brew`, whatever your distro uses) to install the `libczmq-devel` or similar package.

Comment: yes, that helps!

Comment: `dnf search mq-devel ` shows that you want to install `czmq-devel` and `zeromq-devel`: `sudo dnf install czmq-devel zeromq-devel`: Done!

Comment: (oh, and probably `sodium-devel`, too!)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. But sodium package isn't named `sodium-devel`, but `libsodium`. :) Still thanks.